# How can I configure $source_dir to match /Users/${user}/src/${github-owner}/${project}?

Tags: git, puppet, boxen

I'm new to Boxen and I'm trying to create a project manifest that points the correct path for a given project. I organize my source code in `/Users/${user}/src/${github-owner}/${repo}` that matches github urls.

Is there a way to do this with boxen?

For example, here's my configuration for a basic static site:

```
class projects::blog {
  boxen::project { 'blog':
    server_name => 'faun.dev',
    source      => 'faun/blog',
    ruby        => '2.0.0-p353',
    nginx       => "projects/shared/nginx.middleman.conf.erb"
  }
}
```

When I run `boxen`, it places the source code in `/Users/faun/src/blog`, but it really should go in `/Users/faun/src/faun/blog`. Ideally, I'd like to all projects to work this way, since all projects live under the owner directory.

I've tried modifying `$source_dir`, but if I override it, I must provide a fully-qualified path. Is there a way to replace `$source_dir` with some version of `${boxen::config::srcdir}/${github-owner}/${name}` globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration that I ended up with looks like this:

```
class projects::blog {
  boxen::project { 'blog':
    dir         => "${boxen::config::srcdir}/faun/blog",
    server_name => 'faun.dev',
    source      => 'faun/blog',
    ruby        => '2.0.0-p353',
    nginx       => 'projects/shared/nginx.middleman.conf.erb',
  }
}
```

Comment: Good feedback, more complete than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

When I consider [boxen manifest like this one](https://gist.github.com/jfryman/4963514), I see you can define a configuration setup, like:

```
# Configuration Setup
$env = {
  directories => {
    home      => '/Users/jamison',
    dotfiles  => '/Users/jamison/.dotfiles'
  },
}
```

Why not add a `github-owner` in there:

```
  github-owner => 'faun',
```

And use it with `$env['github-owner']` in your `source-dir` override (similar to [L166-L175](https://gist.github.com/jfryman/4963514#file-personal_boxen_manifest-pp-L166-L175)).